# MUI how to implement a free text filter with multiple values

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I am trying to implement a free text filter view with MUI. The Autocomplete component already has that view implemented (when the ['multiple' attribute is set](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#multiple-values)). But I don't want to choose values from a predefined list of options. I want to be able to enter free text sentences.

Any idea on how to implement that?

[image]

Comment: That's what the `freeSolo` option (which can be combined with `multiple`) does. The portion of the docs that you linked to even has an example of this.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell! It worked. I'll post a link to a sandbox with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @RyanCogswell for this suggestion.
Attached are a [link to the solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-dust-jqe7np?file=/demo.js) and the code below:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function KeywordFilter() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      freeSolo
      id="keyword-filter"
      options={[]}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          label="Filter Keywords"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```